# Hybrid Water Heater with Gas Backup?

Tags: water-heater

I've recently become aware of the existence of 'hybrid water heaters' which use a heat pump to heat the water in the tank.  The thing that is appealing to me about this is that the water heater also works as a dehumidifier.  That should, at the very least reduce the need to run a dedicated humidifier and are supposedly even cheaper to run than gas heaters (this probably depends on the cost of electricity and gas)

The examples I've seen all use an electric resistance heater as a backup which is really expensive to run.  Are there hybrid water heaters that have gas backup?  I've seen some discussions about using a tankless heater to augment the hybrid heater but even if that works, it's a lot of up front cost.

Do such units exist?  If not, is there a something about this idea that wouldn't work or is it just that there's no demand or perceived demand?

For context, I've been watching the usage on my dehumidifier for the last 65 days and it's used about 170KWH.  This is probably the highest demand period for that, though.

Comment: Probably no demand. But if you have gas, then a generator might be a better investment than a tankless heater.

Comment: @longneck, the "backup" is for when you need more water than they hybrid system can heat.  They are slower to heat than a standard water heater.  Just like a home heat pump has "aux" heat when its extra cold outside.

Comment: The issue with your questions is that you are assuming the total cost of the heat pump and electricity as backup is too expensive.  Where is the facts behind "electric resistance heater as a backup which is really expensive to run."  The backup electric usage would only come into play at very low temperature.  The unit is located in the house or garage, not outside.  Your home heating is also providing some of the heat in the air, that the heat pump is extracting to heat the water.

Comment: @Programmer66 I'm not sure if you are asking me why I think running electric heat is more expensive than gas but I think that's pretty much common knowledge.  But the other part of your comment is interesting.  That was something I am unsure of.  If the backup doesn't come into play in normal use when capacity is exceeded, then maybe it's more a question of whether these can keep up with our demand.

Comment: @Programmer66 Here's an example: [American® Electric Heat Pump Water Heater](https://www.americanwaterheater.com/new/heat-pump-water-heaters.aspx).  There are separate modes and the 'hybrid' mode combines "... both the heat pump technology and high efficiency heating elements, you save money and quickly enjoy hot water again even after long showers or baths." But it's optional.  I haven't ruled out the tankless backup.  I'll need to do more research.  Luckily I think I have some time to figure this out.

Comment: your  statement was not gas vs electricity cost, but that Electricity as a backup was too expensive.  Backup is the wrong term.  Electric mode can be manually selected if in period of high demand, you want more hot water in a very short period of time.  If you use 40-50 gallons of hot water, you do not necessary need another 20-30 gals right away.  Leave it in heat-pump mode and it will continue to slowly heat up another 40-50 gals.  Even with gas, you used up the capacity, and the gas turns on to heat up another tank full.  Yes gas will be faster,  but very seldom  do we need another tankful

Comment: You could go the whole year and never use the alternate electric mode.  Stay within the 40-50 gal usage and electricity will only be used to run the heat pump.

Comment: Have you considered a split-system heat pump water heater, for that matter?  Also, what is your 99% design heating temperature? (This is probably the biggest variable in determining what sort of system you should get, perhaps even bigger than fuel options in some cases)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Can you point me to an example of what you mean with a split-system?  I'm also seriously considering geothermal which would change everything about this.  I'm seeing data that says the 99% heating temp is -16.5C (around 3.2F.)  I've seen it dip down below 0F a number of times but that seems about right.

Comment: @JimmyJames -- the [Sanden (distributed by ECO2 Systems in the US) SanCO2 (EcoCute) units](https://www.sandenwaterheater.com/) are what you'll find in the US as far as split-system HPWHs go (internationally, Daikin and others make R134a-based units, but those don't seem to be available at all in the North American market)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks.  I'm not sure how the split system is an advantage here.  Wouldn't it eliminate the benefit of dehumidifying my basement?

Comment: @JimmyJames -- split-systems don't provide that dehumidification, but do have the advantage that they don't "parasite load" the heating system during winter (which can be a significant issue in a high-performance envelope).  Furthermore, the SanCO2 system has no need for electric backup heat

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Got it.  I'm not terribly worried about that parasitic load.  The furnace would be a few feet away and it produces a lot of waste heat into non-living space.  Aside from that waste heat, it's basically the earth that controls the temperature in the  space.  In the warm months, (I need to check my numbers but) it looks like 10-20% of my electricity usage is going to dehumidification due to how cool it stays in that space even on 90F+ days.

Comment: @JimmyJames -- the Sanden units do let you install the "outdoor unit" indoors in unconditioned space if you wish.  (Your usecase does make more sense for a unitary/hybrid HPWH than others, though)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I really appreciate your input.  There's not a lot of room in that area so I think the single unit is the way to go.  If it can keep up with the demand, I think this is a slam-dunk option for me.  I'm not sure it would completely dehumidify the space but it should remove some load from the dedicated unit at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I see is that a gas water heater has a big pipe/flue running through the center of it which takes away a lot of room that the hybrid system probably needs. It also vents very hot gas out of the top which is where the compressor is mounted in a hybrid. The electric backup elements are tiny in comparison and just need to stick into the side of the heater.  People with gas, which is normally cheaper than electric, don't have as compelling of a reason to choose a hybrid heater, so I doubt there is much demand.

So, very complex and low demand...  Probably doesn't exist.  I've never seen one.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of what I was thinking.  I found this [paper](https://www.aceee.org/sites/default/files/publications/researchreports/a112.pdf) which has a section titled 'Condensing Gas "Hybrid"' but I'm not sure if that's something else.

Comment: @JimmyJames, looks like those are called "Hybrid" because they are basically the main parts for a gas tankless heater attached to a small tank with a few other features to give better, "buffered" water output.  Condensing just refers to high-efficiency gas heaters where even the exhaust gas is used in the heating process and the output is air that is cool enough to be vented through PVC.  They also require a drain line, because burning natural gas produces water vapor, and cooling the exhaust "condenses" the vapor into liquid water.

Comment: "Condensing just refers to high-efficiency gas heaters where even the exhaust gas is used in the heating process and the output is air that is cool enough to be vented through PVC" Right, that thought occurred to me after I added the comment.

Comment: Gas as an auxiliary to an electric heat pump in one tank would be a nightmare. I cannot believe it exists. Gas fired tank water heaters heat through the bottom and have a flue through the center of the tank. This would be a large route for heat leakage through those surfaces. Electric resistance heating elements project into the tank from the side and have very little heat leakage.

Comment: Where is your water heater located? In a tight closet or in a moderately open room such as a basement?

Answer (score 1):

If you get past the pure economics of a hybrid water heater running in electric resistance mode when it's cold, there's still another consideration.   Keeping the heater out of resistance mode when it's cold outside is going to make the room the heater is in cold.  That's great in the Summer, but it's the last thing one is going to want in the Winter...producing hot water at the cost of a cold room.  Set the heater to pure resistance heating in the Winter though, and the utility bill is going to skyrocket.   Thus, the idea of gas as a secondary energy source is a good one from an economics standpoint.   Many HVAC manufacturers offer "dual fuel" options allowing a heat pump to automatically switch to gas when the outside temperature gets cold, so the engineering is plausible.  The heat pump being on the top of the water heater may constrain the design though, and perhaps this is why don't seem to be around.

Comment: Also think about just how much parasite loss a gas heater has up the flue when the burner isn't firing...and just how few tanked condensing gas heaters there are on the market.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Then, feel free to [edit] your answer to include some formatting - that will make it easier to read and understand. "Wall 'o text" isn't a good communication format...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, the availability of a certain type of heater depends very much on the local market. Over here in the Netherlands, tanked condensing gas heaters are rare (we typically have tankless condensing gas heaters), but in Germany they are almost the norm. And then I am talking about two neighboring countries.